# keyup jquery with different ids (Multi ID Input) for input textbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There are too many database IDs and This is the form code for the product order table (html):

```
1:
<input type="text" name="Quantity" value="100" id="quantity_1">
<input type="hidden" name="Quantity" id="quantity_copy_1">
<br>

2:
<input type="text" name="Quantity" value="200" id="quantity_250">
<input type="hidden" name="Quantity" id="quantity_copy_250">
<br>

3:
<input type="text" name="Quantity" value="300" id="quantity_155">
<input type="hidden" name="Quantity" id="quantity_copy_155">
<br>

4:
<input type="text" name="Quantity" value="400" id="quantity_??">
<input type="hidden" name="Quantity" id="quantity_copy_??">
<br>

<button>Send...</button>
```

[image]

The product number ID is specified in the database , But I don't know what ID is defined for Input.

I want to show the same script code in the form code with different IDs.

```
<script>
$('[id^="quantity"]').keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('[id^="quantity_copy"]').val(value);
}).keyup();
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/behrouzbash/7nqmd0r6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this).next()` or if in a table, `$(this).closest("tr").find(".qty-copy")`

```js
$(".qty").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).next(".qty-copy").val(value);
}).keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1: 
<input type="text" name="Quantity" class="qty" value="100" id="quantity">
<input type="text" name="Quantity" class="qty-copy" id="quantity_copy">

<br>
2: 
<input type="text" name="Quantity" class="qty" value="200" id="quantity_250">
<input type="text" name="Quantity" class="qty-copy" id="quantity_copy_250">

<br>
3: 
<input type="text" name="Quantity" class="qty" value="300" id="quantity_155">
<input type="text" name="Quantity" class="qty-copy" id="quantity_copy_155">

<br>
4: 
<input type="text" name="Quantity" class="qty" value="400" id="quantity_??">
<input type="text" name="Quantity" class="qty-copy" id="quantity_copy_??">

<br>
<button>Send...</button>
```